# MS Teams - detect pop-out was opened

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have an MS Teams "Tab" application. It allows creating a Team tab as well as Personal Tabs. Teams has a feature of the "Pop out tab" button, which opens a clon on my app in the pop-up:
[image]

Is there a way how can I detect opening the "pop out"? For example, a user opened a file for editing in the tab and I don't want to allow him to edit it from the tab and pop-up simultaneously.

Also, is it possible to pass context/app state to the newly opened pop-out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to detect pop-out was opened in teams and it is by design.

Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, we also recommend you give your new idea in Teams UserVoice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/).

Comment: thank you for the response. I noticed there is `isMultiWindow` property in the context - It allows me to detect the apps is in pop-out mode. Is it possible to e.g. send a message to the parent window?